# Check string contains substring in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm building a node application and a module of this application checks whether the nameservers of a given domain name point to AWS.

Using the `dns` module I have the below code:

```
dns.resolveNs(domain, function (err, hostnames) {
    console.log(hostnames);
    console.log(hostnames.indexOf('awsdns') > -1);
});
```

`hostnames` outputs an array of hostnames and the specific domain I've used has the following hostname structure (x4):

```
ns-xx.awsdns-xx.xxx
```

But `console.log(hostnames.indexOf('awsdns') > -1);` returns `false`?

Comment: So hostnames is an array?

Comment: What is the value and type of `hostnames`?

Comment: hostnames is an array. e.g. ['ns-xx.awsdns-xx.xxx', 'ns-xx.awsdns-xx.xxx', 'ns-xx.awsdns-xx.xxx', 'ns-xx.awsdns-xx.xxx']

Comment: A bit curious why you need the check at all, if all of the entries are known to have that substring...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder not all do... obviously. :)

Answer (score 3):

If `hostnames` is an array, then `hostnames.indexOf('awsdns')` is looking for an entry that **exactly matches** (entire string) `'awsdns'`.

To look for substrings in the array, use `some`:

```
console.log(hostnames.some(function(name) {
    return name.indexOf('awsdns') > -1;
});
```

Or with ES6 syntax:

```
console.log(hostnames.some((name) => name.indexOf('awsdns') > -1));
```

**Live Example:**

```js
var a = ['12.foo.12', '21.bar.21', '42.foo.42'];

// Fails there's no string that entirely matches 'bar':
snippet.log(a.indexOf('bar') > -1);

// Works, looks for substrings:
snippet.log(a.some(function(name) {
  return name.indexOf('bar') > -1;
}));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
hostnames[0].indexOf('awsdns') > -1;
```

Since hostnames is an array, you need to check index of an actual hostname, not the array.

Note that this only works because you've said that if *any* of the entries has the substring, they all will. (Which is extremely unusual.) Otherwise, it would fail if the first entry didn't but a subsequent one did.

Comment: He didn't specify. The point of the my answer is to point out what he was doing wrong, not to write write the code for him since he doesn't specify what exactly he needs to do with this.

Comment: Due to the nature of aws nameservers, 'awsdns' will always appear in the first record and there will always only ever be one set of nameservers attached to a domain.

Comment: @leaksterrr: You mean if *any* of them have it, they'll *all* have it, but it's possible that you'll have an array where none of them does? (E.g., not related to AWS...)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, in which case separate handlers are in place for those occurences.

Comment: @leaksterrr: That was *really important information* to include in the question.

Comment: But just looking at the dns.resolveN callback implementation, there is hardly anything in there to tell us what the intention of the callback is. For that reason, it is impossible to guess what may need to be done there. Also, by reading the title of the question, it doesn't seem that the problem is NOT related to the purpose of the callback, but rather the substring check not working. That is the reason I limited the answer to just explain why indexOf was not returning the expected value.

Comment: @GPicazo: In my view, that's a pretty poor way to answer a question. But as of the comments above, the answer is no longer actually *wrong*. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - I apologize for not giving a more detailed/correct answer, but as you said, there isn't enough detail on the question to give a bullet-proof answer.